Solving recurrence involving max
Solve the recurrence:
$$f(n) \leq \sqrt{2}\max_{a\in \{0,\dots,\lfloor n/2\rfloor\} }(\sqrt{a} + f(\lfloor n/2 \rfloor-a)),$$
for all non-negative integers $n$ subject to $$f(0) = 0.$$
From numerical simulation, the result should be $f(n) \leq O(\sqrt{n})$ (no logs -- which is very important for me) but I don't know how to prove this except in the following special cases. If the maximum is always attained at $a=0$, then $f(n) \leq \sqrt{2}f(\lfloor n/2 \rfloor)$ which solves to $f(n) \leq O(\sqrt{n})$. If the maximum is always attained at $a = \lfloor n/2 \rfloor$, then $f(n) \leq O(\sqrt{n})$ as well.

You could start with experimental data by replacing $\le$ by $=$ and computing a few thousands terms.

Thanks for the suggestion. I redid my numerical experiment and it looks like my conjecture is false: the function f(n)/sqrt(n) appears to be growing with n.

Indeed, if we replace "$\le$" by "$=$" then it seems that $\frac 12\le \frac{f(n)}{\sqrt{n\log_2 n}}\le 1$ for any natural $n\ge 2$. I am going to provide more details and the heuristic argument for the lower bound in my answer.

Notice, that I modified my answer below. Now there's a rather full proof in it (based on heuristics).

Claim. $$ f(x) \sim \sqrt{2 x \log_2 x}, \quad x \to \infty.$$
Let's prove it.

$$ \sqrt{2}\max_{a\in \{0,\dots,\lfloor n/2\rfloor\} }(\sqrt{a} + f(\lfloor n/2 \rfloor-a)) \ge (\sqrt{a} + f(\lfloor n/2 \rfloor-a))\bigg|_{a = \lfloor n/2\rfloor} = $$
$$ = \sqrt{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor }   + f(0) \ge 0$$ hence we may take arbitrary $f(n)$ such that $f(n) \le 0$ and $f(0)=0$. E.g. $f(n) =  1- e^n = O(e^n)$ is also a solution. It looks like you implied that $f(n) \ge 0$. Further we will suppose that $f(n) \ge 0$.

There's not only one solution - there's a rather wide class of solutions, so we may speak only about some properties of arbitrary solution from this class. Obviously the smallest solution is $f(n) = 0$ for all $n$. Obviously the biggest solution is obtained if we put $f(0)=0$ and $$f(n) = \sqrt{2}\max_{a\in \{0,\dots,\lfloor n/2\rfloor\} }(\sqrt{a} + f(\lfloor n/2 \rfloor-a)). (*)$$
Thus it sufficies to considers the next problem:
$$f(n) \ge 0, f(0)= 0 \text{ and }  (*) \text{ holds}.$$
Moreover, it looks like we do not solve the recurrence, but just find the asymptotic. If it's true then it makes sense to fix the title of the question.


Further we will use heuristic arguments. We also will write $\frac{n}2$ instead of $\lfloor n/2\rfloor$ and so on.

Let us prove that $f(n) \le n$. By induction
$$f(n) = \sqrt{2}\max_{a\in \{0,\dots,\lfloor n/2\rfloor\} }(\sqrt{a} + f(\lfloor n/2 \rfloor-a)) \le \sqrt{2}\max_{a\in \{0,\dots,\lfloor n/2\rfloor\}} (\sqrt{a} + (\lfloor n/2 \rfloor-a)) = \sqrt{2}\lfloor n/2 \rfloor + \sqrt{2}\max_{a\in \{0,\dots,\lfloor n/2\rfloor\} }(\sqrt{a} -a) =  \sqrt{2}\lfloor n/2 \rfloor + 0 \le n.$$
Similarly we may prove that $f(n) \le \sqrt{2}\lfloor n/2\rfloor$ or $f(n) \le \frac{n}{\sqrt{2}}$ or smth. like that.

Let us prove that $f(x) \ge \sqrt{2} \sqrt{ \lfloor n/2 \rfloor } \approx \sqrt{n}$. Indeed,
$$f(n) = \sqrt{2}\max_{a\in \{0,\dots,\lfloor n/2\rfloor\} }(\sqrt{a} + f(\lfloor n/2 \rfloor-a)) $$ $$\ge \sqrt{2}\max_{a\in \{0,\dots,\lfloor n/2\rfloor\} }(\sqrt{a} + f(\lfloor n/2 \rfloor-a))\bigg|_{a = \lfloor n/2\rfloor\}} = $$
$$= \sqrt{2} (\sqrt{ \lfloor n/2 \rfloor } + f(0) ) = \sqrt{2} \sqrt{ \lfloor n/2 \rfloor } $$


Corollary. We may suppose that $\sqrt{n} \le f(n) \le \frac{n}{\sqrt2}$.
Let us prove that $f(x)$ is a slowly varying function, multiplied by $O(\sqrt{x})$.

It looks like it's more convenient to put $\tilde{a} = \lfloor n/2\rfloor - a$ and get the next problem:
$$f(0)=0, \quad f(n) = \sqrt{2}\max_{a\in \{0,\dots,\lfloor n/2\rfloor\} }(\sqrt{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor - a} + f(a)).$$
And it may be convenient to consider a close problem:
$$ f(0) = 0, \quad f(x) =\sqrt{2}\max_{0 < a < x/2} (\sqrt{x/2-a} + f(a)). (**)$$

It's natural to suppose that $f(n)$ is nondecreasing. There're two main cases:


main case 1: $f(n) =O(\sqrt{n})$
main case 2: $\frac{f(n)}{\sqrt{n}} \to +\infty$.
In the second case it's natural so say that $f(n)$ grows faster that $\sqrt{n}$ and suppose that $f'(x)$ is bigger $(\sqrt{x})'$, i.e. $f'(n) = h(n) \frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}}$ for some $h$ such that $h(x) \to \infty$ as $x\to \infty$.
At first we will consider only main case 2.

Let's find $max_{a \in (0, x/2)} (\sqrt{x/2 - a} + f(a))$. We will suppose that $f'(x) = h(x) (\sqrt{x})'$, where $h(x) \to \infty$ as $x \to \infty$.
Put $g(a) =  (\sqrt{x/2 - a} + f(a))$. Then $g'(a) = \frac{h(a)}{2\sqrt{a}} - \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x/2-a}} = 0$ so $h^2 = \frac{a}{x/2-a} = \frac{1}{\frac{x}{2a} -1}$. So $\frac{x}{2a} = 1+\frac{1}{h^2}$ and $a = \frac{x}2 \frac{1}{1 + h^{-2}}$ is a point where $g(a)$ is maximal. Thus $f(x) = \sqrt{2} max_{u \in (0, x/2)} (\sqrt{x/2 - u} + f(u)) = \sqrt{2}  (\sqrt{x/2 - a} + f(a)) = \sqrt{2}  (\sqrt{x/2 - \frac{x}2 \frac{1}{1 + h^{-2}}} + f(\frac{x}2 \frac{1}{1 + h^{-2}}))$. It follows that
$$ f(x) = \sqrt{2}  (\sqrt{x/2 - \frac{x}2 \frac{1}{1 + h^{-2}}} + f(\frac{x}2 \frac{1}{1 + h^{-2}})) \approx \ \sqrt{x - x \frac{1}{1 + h^{-2}}} + \sqrt{2}f(\frac{x}2),$$
$$ f(x)  \approx \frac{\sqrt{x}}h \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+h^{-2}}}+ \sqrt{2}f(\frac{x}2) \approx \frac{\sqrt{x}}h + \sqrt{2}f(\frac{x}2).$$
It sufficies to solve
$$ f(x) - \sqrt{2}f(\frac{x}2) = \frac{\sqrt{x}}h.$$
Note that $\frac{\sqrt{x}}h = o(\sqrt{x})$ and hence $ f(x) - \sqrt{2}f(\frac{x}2)  = o(\sqrt{x})$. It means that e.g. $f(x) = x^{\frac23}$ is not our case.
Further $h = \frac{f'(x)}{(\sqrt{x})'} \approx \frac{f(x)}{\sqrt{x}}$ by idea of L'Hopital's rule. Thus $f(x) = h(x)\sqrt{x}$. It follows from $ f(x) - \sqrt{2}f(\frac{x}2) = \frac{\sqrt{x}}h$ that
$$\frac{f(x) - \sqrt{2}f(\frac{x}2)}{\sqrt{x}} = \frac1{h}
 = \frac{\sqrt{x}}{f(x)} \Rightarrow$$
$$ f(x)(f(x) - \sqrt{2}f(\frac{x}2)) = x.$$
We saw that $f(x) = h(x)\sqrt{x}$. Thus $$h(x)\sqrt{x} ( h(x)\sqrt{x} - \sqrt{2}h(x/2)\sqrt{x/2}) = x \Rightarrow$$
$$ h(x) ( h(x) - h(x/2)) = 1  \Rightarrow$$
$$h(x) - h(x/2) = \frac{1}{h(x)} \approx 0.$$
Hence $h(x) - h(x/2) \approx 0$ and $h(x)$ is something like const (or $h(x) = \ln \ln \ln x$ or $h(x) = \sqrt{\ln x}$ or smth.like that). So in the second main case (see definition above) we proved that $f(x) = h(x)\sqrt{x} \approx (almost const) \sqrt{x}$. Moreover, $\frac{h(x) - h(x/2)}{h(x)} = \frac{1}{h^2(x)} \approx 0$ so $\frac{h(x/2)}{h(x)}=1$ and it looks like $h(x)$ is slowly varying function.

In  the second main case  we proved that $f(x) = (slowly varying function) \cdot O(\sqrt{x})$ and in  the first main case we also have $f(x) = O(\sqrt{x})$. Hence $$f(x) =  (slowly varying function) O(\sqrt{x}).$$ More precise, $f(x) = h(x) \cdot O(\sqrt{x})$ where either $h(x) = 1$ or $h(x) - h(x/2) = \frac{1}{h(x)} \approx 0.$


9). Addition. Taking into account Alex Ravsky's lower estimate  we see that $h(x) \to \infty$ and hence   $f(x) = h(x) \cdot O(\sqrt{x})$ where  $h(x)$ is slowly varying, $h(x) \to \infty$ and $h(x)$ is such that $h(x)- h(x/2) = \frac{1}{h(x)} \approx 0$.
10). We proved that  $h(x)- h(x/2) = \frac{1}{h(x)} $. Notice that if $h(1)$ is fixed then this equation have unique solution. We will find $c=c_0$ such that $h(x) = c\sqrt{\ln x}$ is a solution and it follows from uniqueness of solution that we found all solutions.
We have $h(x) = c\sqrt{\ln x}$, hence $$h(x)- h(x/2) = c(\sqrt{\ln x} - \sqrt{\ln (x/2)}) = c(\sqrt{\ln x} - \sqrt{\ln x - \ln 2}) =$$
$$ = c\sqrt{\ln x}  (1 - \sqrt{1 - \frac{\ln 2}{\ln x}}) = c\sqrt{\ln x}  (1 - (1 - \frac{\ln 2}{2 \ln x}) = c\sqrt{\ln x}\frac{\ln 2}{2 \ln x} = $$ $$=\frac{c \ln 2}{2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{\ln x}} = \frac{c^2 \ln 2}{2}\frac{1}{c\sqrt{\ln x}} =  \frac{c^2 \ln 2}{2} \frac{1}{h(x)}.$$
So $h(x)- h(x/2) = \frac{1}{h(x)} $ iff $\frac{c^2 \ln 2}{2}=1$ i.e. $c =\sqrt{\frac{2}{\ln 2}}$. So we proved that $h(x) = c\sqrt{\ln x}$ with $c = \sqrt{\frac{2}{\ln 2}}$.
Finally, we have$ f(x) = \sqrt{\frac{2}{\ln 2}} \sqrt{x \ln x}$, i.e.
$$f(x) \sim \sqrt{2 x \log_2 x}.$$

Follows a MATHEMATICA script which implements
$$f(n) = \sqrt{2}\max_{a\in \{0,\dots,\lfloor n/2\rfloor\} }(\sqrt{a} + f(\lfloor n/2 \rfloor-a)),$$
for all non-negative integers $n$ subject to $$f(0) = 0.$$
f[n_] := Module[{max = 0, res = 0, i}, 
  If[n == 0, g[n] = 0; Return[g[n]]];
    For[i = 0, i <= Floor[n/2], i++;
     res = Sqrt[i] + g[Max[Floor[n/2] - i, 0]];
     If[res > max, max = res]
    ];
   g[n] = Sqrt[2] max;
   Return[g[n]]
]

nmax = 1000;
tab = Table[{k, f[k]}, {k, 0, nmax}];
gr1 = ListPlot[tab, PlotStyle -> Red];
Plot[Sqrt[Sqrt[2] x Log[x]], {x, 0, nmax}];
Show[gr1, gr2]

NOTE
I edited the procedure to enhance the recursive performance and to correct a misplaced variable. Now it seems to behave as shown by @Sergei Nikolaev.
In red the sequence values until $n = 1000$ and in blue the function $g(x) = \sqrt{\sqrt{2}(x\ln x)}$


Unfortunately, if we replace "$\le$" by "$=$" then it seems that $\frac 12\le \frac{f(n)}{\sqrt{n\log_2 n}}\le 1$ for any natural $n\ge 2$, see the graph of the function $\frac{f(n)}{\sqrt{n\log_2 n}}$ for $n\in \{2,\dots,8000\}$:

As a heuristic argument for the lower bound consider a function $g(n)=\frac 12\sqrt{n\log_2 n}$. We claim that $g(n)\le \sqrt{2}(\sqrt{a}+g(n/2-a))$ for any $n\ge 5$ and $a=\frac{n}{2\log_2 n}$. Indeed,
we have to check that
$$\frac 12\sqrt{n\log_2 n}\le \sqrt{2}\left(\sqrt{\frac{n}{2\log_2 n}}+
\frac 12\sqrt{\left(\frac n2-\frac{n}{2\log_2 n}\right)\log_2 \left(\frac n2-\frac{n}{2\log_2 n}\right)}
\right)$$
$$\sqrt{\log_2 n}\le 2\sqrt{\frac{1}{\log_2 n}}+
\sqrt{\left(1-\frac{1}{\log_2 n}\right)\log_2 \left(\frac n2-\frac{n}{2\log_2 n}\right)}
$$
$$\log_2 n\le 2+
\sqrt{\left(\log_2 n -1\right)\log_2 \left(\frac n2-\frac{n}{2\log_2 n}\right)}
$$
$$(\log_2 n-2)^2\le \left(\log_2 n -1\right)\log_2 \left(\frac n2-\frac{n}{2\log_2 n}\right)$$
By Lagrange's theorem, for each $0< \Delta\le x$ there exists $y\in (x-\Delta,x)$ such that
$$\frac{\Delta}{y\log_e 2}=\log_2 x-\log_2 (x-\Delta)$$
we have
$$\log_2 \left(\frac n2-\frac{n}{2\log_2 n}\right)\ge \log_2 \frac n2-
\frac{\frac{n}{2\log_2 n}}{\left(\frac n2-\frac{n}{2\log_2 n}\right)\log_e 2}=
\log_2 n-1-\frac{1}{\left(\log_2 n-1\right)\log_e 2}
$$
So it suffices to show that
$$(\log_2 n-2)^2\le \left(\log_2 n -1\right)\left(\log_2 n-1-\frac{1}{\left(\log_2 n-1\right)\log_e 2}\right)$$
$$(\log_2 n-2)^2\le \left(\log_2 n -1\right)^2-\frac{1}{\log_e 2}$$
$$3+\frac{1}{\log_e 2}\le 2\log_2 n,$$
that holds because $n\ge 5$.

It's interesting! The only clarification: it's not a fact that the upper bound is 1 - it doesn't follow from the picture, how big the function will be.

@SergeiNikolaev It seems to me that the picture suggests that the upper bound is (at most) $1$ and I guess this can be shown
similalry to the heuristic argument.
